# Detecting a prop value change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am very new to react. I am currently creating a game and trying to detect if the current turn has changed. I am wondering if there is a simple way to do this.

let hasTurnChanged = props.turn % 2 == 1;

```
  function chooseBestPrice() {
    // start by seeing if prices fluctuate every turn
      let currBestPrice = props.price;
      console.log(hasTurnChanged);
      if(hasTurnChanged){
        currBestPrice = fluctuatePrice(props.price);
      }
      return currBestPrice;
  }
```

When I click a button called Turn the prices are suppose to change.

Comment: I think more details would be helpful for this. Where do you have this function? Is it inside the component or somewhere else?

Comment: It is inside the component known as Inventory Items. There is a variable called turn in App.js which i am trying to monitor for the change.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're trying to detect a prop come from parent component, `useEffect` could help with this.

All we need to do is put the prop into the dependencies array of `useEffect`.

```
const ChildComponent = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // call the function here
  }, [props.price])

  // ...other code
}
```

See the [official document](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) for more information.

Comment: So if I were to use useEffect could I capture the output of the function above in a variable. 
  useEffect(() => {
    bestPrice = chooseBestPrice()
  }, [props.turn])
Would something like this work. Again this change would occur if the turn has changed.

Comment: you're correct.